# Angular: Overwrite styles on fly (apply different color scheme)

Tags: angular

I need to apply **different color schemes** depends on user.

So ideally I would overwrite some styles.
Is there any best practices?
Is it possible to achieve without switching off **Visual Encapsulation**?

Let me provide more details about real usecase.
We have SPA application that provides **SAAS** for consumers. So each company could have **own set of styles** under the same codebase.

Comment: You could just changing CSS classes and design the styles so, that a different class causes a different theme. Otherwise Angular doesn't currently provide anything to override styles at runtime. Ideally styles are compiled ahead of time (before deployment).

Comment: "styles are compiled ahead of time" - I'm thinking how to make it easier. Because in our case during deployment of new styles we would have to rebuild several thousands CSS files :(

Comment: If you add styles globally, they are not subject to encapsulation, only styles added to components.

Comment: so I would need to have not only separate styles for each company but also separate js :(

Comment: I don't know why you think you would have separate JS. If you mean build output, then yes, if you add styles to components that should be different for each customer. If you use global styles, you could do this with some server side templating. Global styles are not affected by compilation.

Comment: There are often styles that don't need to be changed, so you could split them in static styles you add to components and dynamic styles (per customer) added to `index.html`. You could also make some style values configurable by using a configuration file and `[ngStyle]="..."`

Comment: You can also use dynamic module (without AoT compilation), then component styles are rewritten at runtime for encapsulation and you can load the styles dynamically - with some runtime costs.

Comment: sorry, not "separate", but different for each company. So I'll have to provide different build for each company.

Comment: If you want different component styles for each company built AoT, then yes, you need to build for each company.

Comment: may be I could manage to do it with `ExtractTextPlugin`?